# Creat JSON object using php - nested queries

Tags: php, ajax, json

I want to create JSON object using tow query in PHP , Then retrieve this object using ajax . where the first one will return all users . the second nested query will return all tasks associated to particular user . The structure must be like this :

```
{
[
user1 : { "name" : "name1"
          "task" : [ { "taskname":"taskname1.1" , "date":"1-1" } ,

                 { "taskname":"taskname1.2" , "date":"1-1"  }
        }
} ,

user2: { "name" : "name2"
      "task" : [ { "taskname":"taskname2.1" , "date":"2-2" } ,

                 { "taskname":"taskname2.2" , "date":"2-2"  }
               ]
  }
...
]
}
```

my problem is :

when I try to parse each user's tasks , I found that :

each user's tasks are merged with the Previous user(s)' tasks .

So what is the best way to create JSON object with the same structure of mine using php ?

--- update ---

Thanks for everyone who answer me . But I need to know how to create this dynamically , I know how to do this in static and I use json_encode() correctly before , this is not my problem . I really appreciate your answers but this is not what I need and I think the problem is in my question .

Comment: Create an associative array and run `json_encode` on it.

Comment: for quick debuggin, use http://json.parser.online.fr/ and paste your json and see how it evaluates..

Comment: your JSON is completely invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array=array(
    'user1'=>array(
                      'tasks'=>array(
                               'task1'=>'whatever',
                               'task2'=>'whatever',
                               'task3'=>'whatever'
                               ),
                      'date'=>'whatever'
                  ),

    'user2'=>array(
                      'tasks'=>array(
                               'task1'=>'whatever',
                               'task2'=>'whatever',
                               'task3'=>'whatever'
                               ),
                      'date'=>'whatever'
                  ),
    'user3'=>array(
                      'tasks'=>array(
                               'task1'=>'whatever',
                               'task2'=>'whatever',
                               'task3'=>'whatever'
                               ),
                      'date'=>'whatever'
                  )    
);
```

Then use JSON encode to send the JSON string.

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with powerbuoy just create an array with key value pairs in php:

```
$obj = array( 
             "User 1" => array( 
                 "name" => "name1", 
                 "tasks" => array(
                     array("taskname" => "t1", "date" => "1-1"),
                     array("taskname" => "t2", "date" => "1-1")
                 )
             ),
             "User 2" => array(...........)
```

then run `json_encode($obj);`

I think something like that should work for you

Comment: Ahhh Nicolás you beat me to it :)